# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for π

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have application set via Apache httpd acting as reverse proxy.
When I access application directly without reverse proxy it works fine, however with reverse proxy it doesn't 
I can see 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' in developers tool in browser.
which point me to the line in .js file

```
  var Ï€ = Math.PI, Ï„ = 2 * Ï€, halfÏ€ = Ï€ / 2, Îµ = 1e-6, Îµ2 = Îµ * Îµ, d3_radians = Ï€ / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / Ï€;
```

on server actual code is

```
  var π = Math.PI, τ = 2 * π, halfπ = π / 2, ε = 1e-6, ε2 = ε * ε, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;
```

when I do wget on apache host itself I see actual content , but in browser its getting changed.

Do i need to make any changes in httpd? why is getting changed to garbage π

apache version 2.2.15